# WCF service to proxy an email service. Stateful?

Tags: wcf, imap

I have to create a WCF web service that proxies an IMAP service (so that it can be consumed by a SL application).

The IMAP service requires that first the `Login(credentials)` method is called, to authenticate with the IMAP server. After the `Login` method is called the connection is kept open and other operations can be performed.

Does anybody know how can achieve this with a WCF service?

One solution I want to avoid is the proxy to login for every operation it has to perform (as the login operation usually takes 1-2 seconds). And I would have to pass the credentials every time: `GetMail(credentials), GetFolders(credentials),` etc.

I know it is highly recommended that WCF services not to be stateful, but it seems I need to keep the state of IMAP connection for every client. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those rather rare cases where I think using WCF sessions makes sense:

- your first call that calls the IMAP `Login` method starts a WCF session
- any subsequent call will be using the same session
- some final call (e.g. something like a `Done` or `Logout`) will terminate that session

With a session in WCF, your service class on the server stays in memory for the duration of the entire session, i.e. it's not constantly re-created, and thus you can keep the IMAP connection "live" inside your service class.

Resources:

- [Sessions, Instancing, and Concurrency (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193.aspx)
- [Using Sessions (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx)
- [WCF Sessions - a brief introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/Sessions_in_WCF.aspx)
- [WCF Sessions](http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2008/09/07/wcf-sessions/)
- [Per-Session Instance Management in WCF](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1696-per-session-instance-management-wcf-tutorial.aspx)

Be aware: WCF sessions are **NOT** ASP.NET sessions - those are two totally different things! Just to be clear from the get-go.

Also: only a handful of WCF bindings support sessions - `netTcpBinding`, `wsHttpBinding` and `netNamedPipeBinding` (as far as I know)

Comment: Good! That's what I needed.

Do you know if I can use Sessions with a DuplexService (I need it to be duplex to send async message to the SL client)?

Comment: @Matias: I believe yes, you should be able to use wsDualHttpBinding with sessions.